# Undefined symbols for architecture i386: "_objc_assign_ivar". Error when open existed Xcode 3 iPhone project in iOS 4 by Xcode 4

Tags: iphone, xcode4, i386

I have one iPhone project worked fine using Xcode 3. But at that time I opened it by Xcode 4, it raised errors on my first project rebuilding. That error said that:

Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_objc_assign_ivar", referenced from:

- `-[myAppDelegate application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:]` in myAppDelegate.o
- `-[myAppDelegate DoAsynchronousCommand:PARAM_ARRAY:Delegate:]` in myAppDelegate.o
- `-[myAppDelegate connection:didReceiveData:]` in myAppDelegate.o
- `-[myAppDelegate connectionDidFinishLoading:]` in myAppDelegate.o

etc.

ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation).

(Edit: All of necessary libraries were imported and Garbage Collection option was disabled)

I don't know where I have to begin, please show me what wrong? Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: I found out. Just disable Garbage collection in project build setting
.

If you stuck looking for Garbage collection settings all you need to do is to go into your project (the top option in the navigation bar with the big xcode project icon). Select your target which should just be the name of your app with the application icon next to it. When you select that, along the top there is a bar with different options, such as summary, info, build settings etc. Hit “Build Settings” and type “garbage” in the search field. Then set garbage collection to "unsupported". This error was gone.